# DevExpress MVVM - Shared ViewModel & EventToCommand

Tags: c#, winforms, mvvm, devexpress

I'm using DevExpress to add MVVM to my WinForms application. I have a form that contains a ViewModel, which is given to all of its user controls via constructor parameter.

DataBindings are working fine, but I want to add functionality to a ribbonbar by adding EventToCommand behaviour to the usercontrols toolbar item (BarButtonItem).

I do my bindings like this:

```
MVVMContext context = new MVVMContext();
context.ViewModelType = typeof(MyViewModel);
context.WithEvent<MyViewModel, EventArgs>(cmdA, "ItemClick")
            .EventToCommand(x => x.SomeMethod());

context.WithEvent<MyViewModel, EventArgs>(cmdB, "ItemClick")
            .EventToCommand(x => x.SomeOtherMethod());

context.SetViewModel(typeof(MyViewModel), viewModel);
```

viewModel is an instance of MyViewModel that contains the data and is received in the user controls constructor from the form.

However, when running the application, both buttons work but seem to bind to a separate instance of MyViewModel. How can I use the instance that I already have? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have passed the ViewModel instance from the external binding context you should set up your MVVMContext as follows:

```
// View(UserControl) side:
MVVMContext context = new MVVMContext();
// make sure that the MVVMContext will be destroyed when the UserControl destroyed
context.ContainerControl =  this; // your View(UserControl)
context.SetViewModel(typeof(MyViewModel), viewModel);
```

This way prevent the automatic creation of the MyViewModel instance (the automatic creation is used when the context.ViewModelType is specified).

Then you can use the MVVMContext API as usual.

In your case, you can use the `BindCommand` instead of `EventToCommand` because of it specially designed to work with button-objects(like a BarButtonItems).
And, I strongly recommend you use the [Fluent API](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/117019/Build-an-Application/WinForms-MVVM/Concepts/Fluent-API-Support) which provides very clean and maintainable code:

```
var fluent = context.OfType<MyViewModel>();
fluent.BindCommand(cmdA, x => x.SomeMethod());
fluent.BindCommand(cmdB, x => x.SomeOtherMethod());
```